# Xcode SQLite - no such table

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, sqlite

I have a database located in the Resource folder.
This is how I open the database:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dotdDB" ofType:@"sqlite"];
if (sqlite3_open(path, &_database) != SQLITE_OK) {
```

I know that sqlite3_open command creates a new database if it can't find it so that's why I get "no such table"

I've tried to uninstall the app and reset the simulator but still no success.
Any suggestions why I can't find my database in the simulator?

*I use Xcode 3 & sqlite3

Comment: what is the error code that `sqlite3_open` is returning?

Comment: Even though I open this in an if statement and in else I try to NSLog the error nothing happens because it creates a new database. Kinda momentum 22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &_database)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend using [fmdb](http://code.google.com/p/flycode/source/browse/trunk/fmdb) library to interact with sqlite. IMHO, it makes the db operations pretty painless.